# Ошибка libexpat.so.0: cannot open shared object file Centos 7

Tags: linux, сервер, centos

Сервер программы на 32 битной системе. Установленная библиотека есть в папке lib64, но при запуске сервер видимо обращается к папке lib (Я так понимаю 32). Но в сети совершенно не могу найти для 32-ой библиотек таких. 
Я так понял проблема в этом.
Можете подсказать, как исправить эту ошибку? 
Уже опустились руки, не понимаю какое может быть решение.
Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите вывод `$ uname -m; getconf LONG_BIT; file /путь/к/файлу/с/вашей/программой`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin x86_64
64
/home/server/Connector/Connector/run: sticky Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

Comment: 1. вы, вроде бы, далеко не новичок, потому я и не писал «приложите к тексту вопроса». 2. подставьте в команду путь к **программе**, а не к скрипту. к той самой программе, которую загрузчик не может загрузить, не находя библиотеки expat.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Добавил. Надеюсь правильно вас понял.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса